# Is there a way to reduce the CPU and memory usage of the stock Browser?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread, browser, ram

The stock browser in Gingerbread 2.3.3 seems to take a lot of resources in terms of CPU and memory.  This causes other apps, including the launcher, to be killed.  Are there any steps I can take to reduce the footprint of the browser?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (AT&T Captivate) running a ROM based on Gingerbread 2.3.3.

Comment: One obvious solution is to use a third-party browser.

Comment: Most (all?) are worse, though.  Did this happen to you with other ROMs?  Are you using the stock launcher?

Comment: @Al, true, but there's a service I run that only work with the stock browser.  Otherwise I'd consider Dolphin.  Wasn't a fan of Firefox.

Comment: @Matthew, looking at the ROM page it says AOSP launcher.  (http://serendipity7.weebly.com/index.html) Not sure what that is.  It does seem to be worse with my Gingerbread ROM as opposed to my previous FroYo ROM. Both done by same people (Serendipity).

Comment: AOSP = Android Open-Source Project. In other words, it's the same launcher that would come with a Nexus device. It doesn't look like they've removed Samsung's Touchwiz from the ROM, so that might be one reason it gets killed so much -- the AOSP launcher is not the special-built-in-don't-kill-me launcher. Admittedly I'm not clear on how that works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things I know of are turning off images, Javascript and plugins.  You probably don't want to do all that but setting plugins to "On demand" is quite useful -- pages with Flash ads and such won't waste your data or battery in addition to demanding less from your phone, and it's just one click to allow a particular object to run if you want to watch an embedded video or something.

Comment: Would clearing cache improve performance significantly?

Comment: @Chance I don't think so, that would force a fresh/complete download of every web page you visit which would just use *more* resources.

Comment: That's what I thought.  My performance seems to be much better recently, and the things I can think of is that I deleted the Google search box widget from my home page, used OCLF and changed minfree to strict, and changed Googlesearch settings to not search text messages.  I think the last thing improved Google app performance, but I don't know if it would affect browser.